# Some array elements changing from within function to inside main function in C program

Tags: c

I am writing a C program to get a list of all the files in a given directory. It takes a command-line input representing the file path of the directory from which user wants the files listed. The function returns a string array where each element is one of the files in the directory. Right now, I am having each elements be not just the file name but the entire file path. So here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>

char **show_dir_content(char *path)
{
    char **files;
    int number_of_files = 5;
    int i = 0;
    files = (char **)calloc(number_of_files, sizeof(char *));
    DIR *d = opendir(path);
    if (d == NULL)
        return files;
    struct dirent *dir;
    while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
    {
        if (dir->d_type != DT_DIR)
        {
            int path_len = strlen(path);
            files[i] = (char *)calloc(strlen(dir->d_name) + path_len + 1, sizeof(char));
            sprintf(files[i], "%s/%s", path, dir->d_name);
            printf("%d:  %s\n", i, files[i]);
            i++;
            if (i == number_of_files)
            {
                number_of_files += 5;
                files = (char **)realloc(files, number_of_files * sizeof(char *));
            }
        }
    }
    return files;
}


int main(int arcv, char *argv[])
{
    char **files = show_dir_content(argv[1]);
    int i;
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; files[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        printf("%d:  %s\n", i, files[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; files[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        free(files[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the output is funky to say the least when I enter my current directory as input. So I output 2 different ways. Inside my show_dir_content function, I print each element of the array right after I get the file. And then in the main function, I loop through the array returned from the show_dir_content function, printing each element. If the program was printing properly, both results should be the same but for some reason they are not and I don't know why.

```
0:  ./file2.txt
1:  ./file1.txt
2:  ./find-file-size.h
3:  ./find-file-size.o
4:  ./get-files.o
5:  ./get-files.h
6:  ./Makefile
7:  ./get-dir-size.h
8:  ./get-dir-size.o
9:  ./get-files.c
10:  ./find-file-size.c
11:  ./get-dir-size.c
12:  ./fsz

0:  ./file2.txt
1:  ./file1.txt
2:  ./find-file-size.h
3:  ./find-file-size.o
4:  ./get-files.o
5:  ./get-files.h
6:  ./Makefile
7:  ./get-dir-size.h./get-dir-size.o./get-files.c
8:  ./get-dir-size.o./get-files.c
9:  ./get-files.c
10:  ./find-file-size.c
11:  ./get-dir-size.c
12:  ./fsz
```

As you can see, for the most part, it is correct, except for elements 7 and 8. If anyone can explain why there is a disparity between those 2 elements from within the show_dir_content function to what is printed in the main function, that would be helpful.

Comment: `files[i]` has a type `char*` so this is already wrong: `files[i] != '\0'`. Didn't look further.

Comment: you might like the versatile `scandir()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things: (1) you need to allocate one additional character to cover also the necessary string termination character `'\0'`. (2) you should explicitly mark the end of the list with `NULL`, as you cannot rely that a `realloc` fills the memory block with zeros (with `calloc` you can rely on that, but not with `realloc`):

```
while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)    {
        ...
        // note the +2, one for the '/' and one for the string termination character
        files[i] = (char *)calloc(strlen(dir->d_name) + path_len + 2, sizeof(char));  
        sprintf(files[i], "%s/%s", path, dir->d_name);
        ...
}
files[i] = NULL;
```

The reason for the (undefined) behaviour you observe is probably part (1);  the string termination character written by a first `sprintf` is out of the memory range allocated; a second `calloc` could start right at the string termination character of the first one, and the second's `sprintf` overwrites this string termination character. It thereby "concatenates" the two strings (from the viewpoint of the first one).

Comment: thanks. that helped. changing the +1 to a +2 solved my issue.